# Map two different data-frame with common row and combining them together

Tags: r

This is the data-frame

**A**

```
 gene
 ENSG00000000938
 ENSG00000001617
 ENSG00000001630
 ENSG00000002330
 ENSG00000002726
 ENSG00000002822
```

The row which would be common across the other data frame is the third column

**Expression dataframe**

```
gene log2FoldChange
     ENSG00000000938       4.247333
     ENSG00000001617       3.381206
     ENSG00000001630       2.148626
     ENSG00000002330       2.876010
     ENSG00000002822       2.508205
```

****>     **Region dataframe******

```
gene log2FoldChange
     ENSG00000000938       8.247333
     ENSG00000001617       1.381206
     ENSG00000001630       6.148626
     ENSG00000002330       3.876010
     ENSG00000002726       1.602266
```

So i want to map the A with both the column `expression dataframe and Region dataframe` Such that I would like to to end up like this

My final data-frame should be looking something like this

**Output expected**

```
gene                log2FoldChange_Expression log2FoldChange_Region
 ENSG00000000938          4.247333                8.247333
 ENSG00000001617          3.381206                1.381206
 ENSG00000001630          2.148626                6.148626
 ENSG00000002330          2.876010                3.876010
```

The approach i tried is

**Step 1** Inner join the dataframe A with Expression dataframe
**Step 2** Inner Join the datafameA with region dataframe

The trying to paste each dataframe in a single dataframe. Im not sure if this is the right approach

Comment: The inner join approach should give you the answer. `res <- merge(merge(A, Expression, by = 'gene'), Region, by = 'gene')`

Comment: okay i have to add the merge as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach, so make sure your datasets are in data.table format. If not, you can uncomment the setDT(...) line in the code below.

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
library(tibble)
A <- fread("gene
 ENSG00000000938
 ENSG00000001617
 ENSG00000001630
 ENSG00000002330
 ENSG00000002726
 ENSG00000002822")
expression <- fread("gene log2FoldChange
     ENSG00000000938       4.247333
     ENSG00000001617       3.381206
     ENSG00000001630       2.148626
     ENSG00000002330       2.876010
     ENSG00000002822       2.508205")
region <- fread("gene log2FoldChange
     ENSG00000000938       8.247333
     ENSG00000001617       1.381206
     ENSG00000001630       6.148626
     ENSG00000002330       3.876010
     ENSG00000002726       1.602266")
```

**code**

```
#put data in a named list, 
L <- tibble::lst(A, expression, region)
#loop over the list's L indexes
L <- lapply(seq_along(L), function(x) {
  #if data is not yet in data.table format, convert it
  # setDT(L[[x]])  # <-!! uncomment if your data is not already data.table
  #set the key (gene) to join on
  setkey(L[[x]], gene)
  #if the data has more than two columns, add a suffix to the columns 2 and higher
  #based on the name if the data (derived from the list L's names)
  if (x > 1) {
    output <- setnames(L[[x]], 
             grep("^(?!gene)", names(L[[x]]), value = TRUE, perl = TRUE),
             paste0(grep("^(?!gene)", names(L[[x]]), value = TRUE, perl = TRUE), "_", names(L)[x]))
  } else {
  #else return the data as-is
    output <- L[[x]]
  }
  #return output
  return(output)
})
#step over list L, and merge them al together
#reduce join
Reduce( function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), L )
```

**output**

```
#               gene log2FoldChange_expression log2FoldChange_region
# 1: ENSG00000000938                  4.247333              8.247333
# 2: ENSG00000001617                  3.381206              1.381206
# 3: ENSG00000001630                  2.148626              6.148626
# 4: ENSG00000002330                  2.876010              3.876010
# 5: ENSG00000002726                        NA              1.602266
# 6: ENSG00000002822                  2.508205                    NA
```

Comment: this looks bit complicated as i dont use loop etc much but i will learn it part by part

Comment: I added some additional comments to explain things a bit more.

Comment: This solution worked absolutely fine. Here I had like two dataframe will this work if i have more than 2 dataframe?

Comment: it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do this by matching the order of the two datasets and using cbind to bind the columns from each dataset together, now they're sorted.
**Assuming the two datasets have the same set of genes**:

`Exp_data<-Exp_data[match(Reg_data$gene,Exp_data$gene),]` #reorder the rows of Exp_data so the gene names match the order found in Reg_data

`identical(Exp_data$gene,Reg_data$gene)` #If the genes are now in exactly the same order in Exp_data and Reg_data, this should return 'TRUE'

`combined_data<-cbind(Exp_data,Reg_data)` #bind the datasets together in column by column manner and assign it to a new object called combined_data

I find this a very straightforward way of thinking about this but I **always** check the ordering of lists, as 'match' is easily misused.